# Shorter code in matlab to minimize data and getting corresponding indices

Tags: matlab, if-statement, simplify

**EDIT** How to simplify the following code:

```
if(x(a) > x(b))
  s = b;
  e = a;
else
  s = a;
  e = b;
end
```

I can get it shorter like:

```
s = a;
e = b;
if(x(a) > x(b))
  s = b;
  e = a;
end
```

Thanks!

**EDIT**

```
h = [a b]; 
[~, idx] = min([x(a) x(b)]);
s = h(idx)
e = h(3-idx)
```

Comment: Why do you set `s` and `e` before the comparison? If you eliminate the first two lines, it's about as simple as it gets.

Comment: Because it's already a bit shortened :) Look at my edit :)

Comment: Are you doing this inside loops over `a` and `b` ? If so, there might be a better way...

Comment: @Edric: No I haven't! Further I found a solution to it. It's not absolutely necessary to find the shortest solution, I just though that there's perhaps a matlab one-liener and I'm missing something easy...

Comment: @Col, your first two codes outputs the indices, but in your EDIT it ouputs the vaules. What do you want?

Comment: @Oli: Argh sorry for the confusion, I edited my edit to get the indices, not the values :-)

Comment: Wtf sorry, but why voting down on this one? I don't get some people as it's a legimate question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure your code does what you wanted it to do?

Maybe you want to try

```
s = min([x(a),x(b)]);
e = max([x(a),x(b)]);
```

EDIT: OK there you go,

```
r = [find(x==max(x), find(x==minx)];
```

you have what you need in `r` but if you need them as `s` and `e` then:

```
s = r(1);
e = r(2);
```

Comment: I don't want the actual values `x(a)` and `x(b)` being minimized. I want to set the index of the smaller value of `x` to be set to `s` and the bigger value to be set to `e`. Look at the edit in my original post!